# Return only one value when table cell contains multiple tr and td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a smaller table with multiple tr and td elements which is part of bigger table bgtable .When I click on that smaller table I have a anchor tag to redirect to some page (this must have to be on click on smaller table). Now my onclick event on this table returning Data1 , Data2 and Data3 all together. How can I capture only last td data which is Data3 always using Jquery ? 
my below code returning all td data which I don't want.

so

```
<a href="www.example.com">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> Data1 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Data2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> Data3 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</a>
```

then my JQ :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bgtable td").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
  });
});
```

Note: I can't change my onclick but I have to get the "Data3". Tried `($("td:last".text() )`. Not helpful and returns nothing

Comment: Unclear... in the real use-case... I understand there is a nested table.
--- Try `$(".bgtable td").last().on(...` But that can't be correctly answered since your HTML looks way too "minimal" as per [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It also has to be complete. And the table (or any container classname) doesn't show int the HTML.

Comment: And I do not question the wrapping anchor yet....

Comment: louys-patrice-bessette - Sorry this is a skeleton code . if you forget the anchor for now (my bad !) the intention is to click on the mini table (this has to be ) as I have other dependent code wrapped around so I can't change my onclick but want to retrieve the text "Data3" . I tried using td:last of Jquery not giving me any data just null . I mean : $("td:last").text() ) ;

Comment: You can try using `$(this).parent().parent().find("td:last").text()` (assuming `bgtable` class is applied to table)

Comment: @PhaniKumarM - it doesn't work because my minitable is a 30 day calendar and it scans through all 30 days plus returns last date text of that calendar and not the one which I clicked

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... finally it is working with below :

```
$(this).find("td:last").text() ;
```

Do anybody knows how to get the one element before last one ?